# Need help in MySQL statement syntax to Sum Time

Tags: mysql, select

i need help in MySQL select statement i want to make query 
to sum over time while ignoring the record if it is less than ten minutes
Example:

```
02:00
01:30
00:15
00:09 ignore
00:03 ignore
result Should be 03:45
```

i try the following:

```
Select SEC_TO_TIME( sum(TIME_TO_SEC(overtime))) AS Late
FROM reports  ;
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select SEC_TO_TIME( sum(TIME_TO_SEC(overtime))) AS Late
FROM reports
where overtime >= '00:10:00'
```